# Google Calendar Api >net-Time out exception on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I created the sample Asp.net application to get all the calender and add event in a calendar.My Application is working fine when i run it using Visual Studio it successfully load the page,show all calendar info, add event in calendar.But when i deploy the app on IIS, page never load and it gives the "Request timed out" exception.Kindly help

Following is the code

```
private CalendarService InitGoogleService()
{
UserCredential credential;
string path = Server.MapPath("~") + @"\GCSc.json";
string credPath = Server.MapPath("~") + @"\Calendar_Data";
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
{
ClientId = "My Client Id",`enter code here`
ClientSecret = "My Client Secret"
}, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, new Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore(credPath)).Result;

    CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
    return service;
}
```

[Request Timeout Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aClfN.jpg)
[image]

Comment: When you deploy it is it does it request authentication?    What do you have the redirect uri set to?  What application pool do you have IIS running as?  is there anything in credPath directory on the server?

Comment: I have seen this issue a number of times in the past I think its time we nail it for good I am going to try and recreate your problem.

Comment: any update to resolve the issue?